# RPSystemBroadcastPickerView not showing preferredExtension

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, broadcast, ios-app-extension

I use RPSystemBroadcastPickerView to show user list of broadcast service.

```
let broadcastPickerView = RPSystemBroadcastPickerView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 51, height: 51))
view.addSubview(broadcastPickerView)
broadcastPickerView.preferredExtension = "com.someApp.someTeam.broadcast-extension"
```

I've set correct app extension bundleId in to preferedExtension but it isn't show my app in list.
Also main target and extension target have same groupID and deployment target.

I read all the available information about my problem and tried all of advice bu they didn't help.

iOS 16.5 xcode 14.3